# How to extract an image file from System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs in C#

Tags: c#, image, printing

I want to save the printing invoice into an image file. but generic GDI+ error occurs.

MWC:

```
public partial class FormInvoice : Form
{
    public FormInvoice()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.prnDocument = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();

        prnDocument.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(prnDocument_PrintPage);

    }


private void prnDocument_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{

    leftMargin = (int)e.MarginBounds.Left;
    rightMargin = (int)e.MarginBounds.Right;
    topMargin = (int)e.MarginBounds.Top;
    bottomMargin = (int)e.MarginBounds.Bottom;
    InvoiceWidth = (int)e.MarginBounds.Width;
    InvoiceHeight = (int)e.MarginBounds.Height;

    // some codes go here that draw on e.graphics            

    //SetInvoiceHead(e.Graphics); // Draw Invoice Head
    //SetOrderData(e.Graphics); // Draw Order Data
    //SetInvoiceData(e.Graphics, e); // Draw Invoice Data

    Graphics g = e.Graphics;

    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.FromHbitmap(g.GetHdc()); // generates error            
    bmp.Save("invoices\\a.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think `HDC` and `HBITMAP` can be used interchangeable. What kind of error do you get?

Comment: That's not possible, the e.Graphics argument of the PrintPage event doesn't refer to a bitmap.  Printer drivers use metafiles.  Just write a method named, say, DrawPage(Graphics gr).  Which you can now call from your PrintPage event handler.  *And* from code that creates a Bitmap and uses Graphics.FromImage().  Now you can do it both ways.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. Would you please provide me a sample code or a link. I googled it but no result.